# c# кастомный компонент

Tags: c#, winforms, компоненты

Встречали ли вы кастомный компонент "трекбар" с несколькими ползунками, каждый из которых задает некий рендж значений?

Или, хотя бы на крайний случай -- просто трекбар в котором ты задаешь рендж значений.

Comment: Только слайдеры встречал кастомные и из коробки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для будущих поколений:

Кастомизация/рефакторинг оригинального компонента:

https://github.com/ukushu/RangeBarComponent

Оригинальный компонет:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2275/C-RangeBar-control

Описание изменений по отношению к оригинальному в ридми.

Answer (score 0):

Вот общее, так сказать, описание из книги Тролсена: [Элемент TrackBar](https://it.wikireading.ru/31324).

А это подробнейшее описание создания собственного контрола: [Создание собственных элементов управления](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171725(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: дело в том, что не хочется изобретать велосипед. Должны же быть готовые контролы.

Comment: @Andrew http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/slider.aspx https://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, оба WPF. В вопросе стоит WinForms tag. =(

Comment: @Andrew https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/649xahhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx на msdn есть цикл статей про кастомизацию контрола, думаю можно собрать что нибудь